# Is the "Posts page" really required? Can problems occur if I leave it blank?

Tags: blog-page

I read some scary comments [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-blog-to-json-ld-breadcrumbs). (By *Blog page*, he means the *Posts page* in the reading settings.)

> The Blog Page gives out several indicators to social sites and Search Engines that it's a Blog. [...] In fact, WordPress requires a Blog page to be available. Failing to do so may cause bugs in some plugins and themes, and even within WordPress itself. [...] The Blog page is a reserved item within WordPress. Many WordPress functions and queries are written around this item.

Is the *Posts page* really required? Can problems with plugins or Google occur if I leave it blank?

(Reason for asking: I want to use a parent category "blog" instead of a *Posts page*.)

Comment: Not sure what is the question ;) but if you ask about best SEO practice then this is most likely the wrong place to ask about that

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't need to include a posts page on your site. Plenty of sites consist of just some pages and no posts at all.

However, Google uses the posts pages to find links to your individual posts. If there is no such page you will need a different structure to guide Google (for instance through the menu, by including a dropdown of your child categories). Given that Google's algorithms are secret I cannot know whether using an uncommon navigation structure is better or worse for seo.

Comment: I want to assign "blog" as the parent category to all posts and show my blogs posts in that category archive page. So effectively that will serve the same function as a "posts page". I'm just worried that not having the standard "posts page" _"**may cause bugs** in some plugins and themes, and **even within WordPress itself**."_ Can the lack of the standard "posts page" really cause bugs in WP when you do have posts?

Comment: In this setup you'll have no issue with Google. There are millions of WordPress sites without a blog style posts page, so you shouldn't worry about joining them.